# Image size restricted and facebook not recognising og:image

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, netsuite

I am working within a Netsuite content management system and have image restrictions for displaying in an e-commerce portal - we can only display a thumb nail or main product image at 270 x 361.

If Facebook insists of an og:image of at least 600 x 315 pixels - how do I accommodate this? Should I upload a perfect 'Facebook' version to server and simply link back to Open Graph tags?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing is done client side (sometimes server with tags), can you put that on the display page? Else yes, just resize them.